# How do I name images by barcode as I am photographing?

Tags: file-management, filenames

I need to create a system whereby I can scan a barcode and every picture taken after that code is scanned is sequentially named with that barcode and then when the next barcode is scanned, the images are named with that code etc...

As an example
SCAN: CODE12345
PIC 1 CODE12345_001
PIC 2 CODE12345_002

SCAN: CODE56789
PIC 3 CODE56789_001
PIC 4 CODE56789_002

...
..
.

Any help would be totally appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but to me that sounds like a problem to be answered by coders, not photographers. Am I right that you are looking for a piece of software to do this?

Comment: This is essentially a computing problem rather than a photography one. If *I* was doing this I'd use a raspberry pi with its dedicated camera and openCV. You could also run this on a desktop renaming the files in sequence based on inspecting them for barcodes. But whatever approach you take it will almost certainly involve writing code.

Comment: I think most cameras are limited to 8-character filenames in order to avoid some old file system patents.

Comment: I have never seen a camera with a barcode scanner, or even one attached.